# Blender GUI freezes when running interactive python console

Tags: python, command-line

When starting blender from the command line with:

```
blender.exe --python-console
```

The blender GUI seems freezed and says "Keine Rückmeldug" - no response.

[image]

I am using blender 2.81a portable. My guess is, the process running the gui is interfering with the process running the interactive console. But i'd like to use the interactive console and the blender gui at the same time. Is there a way i can do that? Am i doing something wrong?

Greetings,
Mamu

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work as far as I'm aware. The behavior is the same in 2.79, 2.80, 2.81 and 2.82. Your command line should show the python console though.

Comment: ... for example can `>>> bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile("foo.blend")` run other commands, and when done, exiting the python console with ctrl-D prints the message "now exiting InteractiveConsole..." loads and focuses blender window.

Comment: is there a way to go back into interactive python shell after doing ctrl-D, say for more scripting, then ctrl-D again to see the updates?